# failing to restart solr server

Tags: solr, solrj

I just installed a Hebrew plugin in Solr and tried restarting the server to use it.
I used this (my core is called techproducts):

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/admin/cores?action=RELOAD&core=techproducts
```

What I got In response is this error, seams like I placed the files in the wrong place:

```
    {
  "responseHeader":{
    "status":500,
    "QTime":832},
  "error":{
    "metadata":[
      "error-class","org.apache.solr.common.SolrException",
      "root-error-class","java.lang.IllegalArgumentException"],
    "msg":"Unable to reload core [techproducts]",
    "trace":"org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to reload core [techproducts]\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reload(CoreContainer.java:1414)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.lambda$static$2(CoreAdminOperation.java:131)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminOperation.execute(CoreAdminOperation.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler$CallInfo.call(CoreAdminHandler.java:395)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.admin.CoreAdminHandler.handleRequestBody(CoreAdminHandler.java:180)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:199)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdmin(HttpSolrCall.java:734)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.handleAdminRequest(HttpSolrCall.java:715)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:496)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:377)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:323)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1634)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:533)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1317)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1219)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:219)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:126)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.rewrite.handler.RewriteHandler.handle(RewriteHandler.java:335)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:531)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:352)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:281)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:762)\r\n\tat org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:680)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core techproducts: Can't load schema c:\\Program Files\\solr-7.5.0\\example\\techproducts\\solr\\techproducts\\conf\\managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType \"text_general\": Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.reload(CoreContainer.java:1391)\r\n\t... 39 more\r\nCaused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Can't load schema c:\\Program Files\\solr-7.5.0\\example\\techproducts\\solr\\techproducts\\conf\\managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType \"text_general\": Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:584)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.<init>(IndexSchema.java:181)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchema.<init>(ManagedIndexSchema.java:105)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:173)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.create(ManagedIndexSchemaFactory.java:45)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchemaFactory.buildIndexSchema(IndexSchemaFactory.java:75)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.createIndexSchema(ConfigSetService.java:119)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:92)\r\n\t... 40 more\r\nCaused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType \"text_general\": Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:182)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.IndexSchema.readSchema(IndexSchema.java:475)\r\n\t... 47 more\r\nCaused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.readAnalyzer(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:302)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:95)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.create(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.util.plugin.AbstractPluginLoader.load(AbstractPluginLoader.java:152)\r\n\t... 48 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: path to hspell data folder couldn't be found\r\n\tat com.code972.hebmorph.hspell.HSpellLoader.getHspellPath(HSpellLoader.java:117)\r\n\tat com.code972.hebmorph.hspell.HSpellDictionaryLoader.loadDictionaryFromDefaultPath(HSpellDictionaryLoader.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewAnalyzer.<init>(HebrewAnalyzer.java:63)\r\n\tat org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer.<init>(HebrewQueryAnalyzer.java:38)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:584)\r\n\tat org.apache.solr.schema.FieldTypePluginLoader.readAnalyzer(FieldTypePluginLoader.java:286)\r\n\t... 51 more\r\n",
    "code":500}}
```

I think the problem is with the location of the plugin files. If you know where should I be placing the files, do tell me. Any help would be app-reciated! thanks!

Comment: Which version of Solr/Lucene are you using

Comment: version 7.5.0. the newest.

Comment: Is it possible that HebMorph only supports up to Lucene/Solr 6.2? Not 7.x? https://github.com/synhershko/HebMorph

Comment: maybe, I'll try if nothing else works.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to add H-spell files to the route. Silly mistake.
the server restarts now, but it still doesn't seem like the plugin is integrated.
thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Solr will show which directories it looks in for jar files when starting up, so if you watch the Solr log you'll see what the existing options are.

However, you can [add your own directory (and pattern) to the list of existing directives](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/lib-directives-in-solrconfig.html). These go in `solrconfig.xml` for your core:

```
<lib dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

Replace the path given in `dir=".."` with the path to the directory containing your own jar files.

Comment: dir="../../../contrib/extraction/lib" should be replaced or should I leave /contrib/extraction/lib" in? either way I kind of did that already:        <lib path="C:/Users/אסתר/.m2/repository/com/code972/hebmorph/hebmorph-lucene/6.6.1hebmorph-lucene.jar" />

Comment: also, what is r/n/tat ?

Comment: I have no idea if there's a parameter named `path` - the documentation and my example uses `dir`. The `dir` argument should point to the directory containing your jars - so in this case it'd be something like `<lib dir="C:/Users/אסתר/.m2/repository/com/code972/hebmorph/hebmorph-lucene" regex=".*\.jar" />`. The `\n\tat` are formatting commands, the `\n` means newline, the `\t` means a tab sign and the `at` is just the word `at` - if the stack trace was printed to console, it'd make sure that each `at` lined up slightly indented on each line.

Comment: still doesn't work. I think I've set the path to Hebmorph itself correctly. the problem is (I think) with the extra Hspell files (dictionary files). according to the Hebmorph readme file:  
"Add the following line to solrconfig.xml which can be found at solr/<i>collection1</i>/conf directory, within your solr-instanceDir. For example [solr home]/<i>example</i>/solr/<i>collection1</i>/conf/solrconfig.xml.
```
    <lib path="PATH/TO/hebmorph-lucene.jar" /> 
```
Replace PATH/TO/hebmorph-lucene.jar with the location of your hebmorph-lucene.jar"

Comment: You can see if the jar file is being loaded in the startup log as mentioned in my answer. If the jar file doesn't show up as being loaded there, the `lib` instruction is probably your problem. `path` seems to be supported from that, so start by finding out if it's being loaded at all.

Comment: alright, checking now, thanks.  seams like it doesn't load really: 
...at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core techproducts: Can't load schema c:\Program Files\solr-7.5.0\example\techproducts\solr\techproducts\conf\managed-schema: Plugin init failure for [schema.xml] fieldType "text_general": Cannot load analyzer: org.apache.lucene.analysis.hebrew.HebrewQueryAnalyzer
 at org.apache.solr.core.ConfigSetService.getConfig(ConfigSetService.java:97)

Comment: Could you please help me out here? I really have no idea on how to fix it.  I am on the verge of converting the project to English because I am having so much trouble with this tool.

Comment: If the startup log doesn't show the jar file being loaded - but shows other libraries being loaded - then you're still missing the correct `<lib ...>` directive. Unless Solr is able to load the jar file, you won't be able to reference the plugin (which according to your comment is still what's the issue).

Comment: alright thanks. is it possible that because the route is using none standard characters (hebrew characters) it's failing to load it?

Comment: It was much simpler than that: I forgot to add the hspell files route to the config.xml. Thanks for the help and Sorry for bothering you guys. That mistake was so stupid.